# Why some UTF-8 characters falls into some weird squares with four digits?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I find some UTF-8 characters falls into some weird squares with four digits in my terminal like this:

[image]

Could anyone please explain why that weird squares appears instead of correct UTF-8 characters?

PS:

The correct message is(you can look up UTF-8 tables to get that):

```
reboot: 只有 root 能够执行
```

Which means `reboot: Only root can execute`.

PPS:

I test UTF-8 characters with 5 or 6 hex digit:

[image]

Wow, I got a square with six digits inside!

Many thanks to Jonathan!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means your font doesn't have a symbol for U+80FD or U+591F (etc), so the square is a fallback that allows you to determine what the Unicode symbol was, even though the glyph cannot be displayed accurately.

You either need to get a new font or change locale or something along those lines so that you get to see the message more nearly correctly.

Comment: I wonder, what happens if my font have no symbol for a five hex UTF-8 character (such as U+12345), a square with five digits?

Comment: I'm not sure; you'd have to experiment.  It is possible that it would be encoded as two UTF-16 surrogates (a high surrogate in the range U+D800..U+DBFF and a low surrogate in the range U+DC00..U+DFFF).  These would each fit into one of the 4-digit boxes neatly.  It's the technique used in JSON for encoding Unicode characters outside the BMP (basic multilingual plane).  Or it might squeeze a fifth character into the box, somehow.  Or …

Comment: I tested it and add the result to my questions. It's a square with six digits inside. Thanks your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Those glyphs are missing in the font you are using, so their hexadecimal number is rendered instead. Make your terminal use a font with CJK characters.